# How can I upload an image to server in codenameone and retrieve back?

Tags: java, php, codenameone

hi i am trying to upload an image from device using codenameone and upload it to php server and storing the image Url in mysql database and then wanna retrive that image back  to show on device but its not working properly
Below is my java code

```
jobIcon.addActionListener((ActionEvent en) -> {
           if(Dialog.show("Camera or Gallery", "Would you like to use the camera or the gallery for the picture?", "Camera", "Gallery")) {
             jobPic = Capture.capturePhoto();
            if(jobPic != null) 
                try{
          Image img = Image.createImage(jobPic);
             ImageIO imgIO= ImageIO.getImageIO();
             ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             imgIO.save(img, out,ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 1);
           bytesdata = out.toByteArray();
             jobIcon.setIcon(img);
            
            }catch(IOException err) {
                        ToastBar.showErrorMessage("An error occured while loading the image: " + err);
                        Log.e(err);
                    }
        } else {
            Display.getInstance().openGallery(ee -> {
                if(ee.getSource() != null) {
                    try {
                        jobPic =(String)ee.getSource();
                      Image img = Image.createImage((String)ee.getSource());
                      ImageIO imgIO= ImageIO.getImageIO();
                      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                      imgIO.save(img, out,ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 1);
                      bytesdata = out.toByteArray();
                      jobIcon.setIcon(img);
                   
                    } catch(IOException err) {
                        ToastBar.showErrorMessage("An error occured while loading the image: " + err);
                        Log.e(err);
                    }
                }
            },Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
```

I don't want to display the image right after that and if I remove Display.GALLERY_IMAGE it shows error,
and then  I am sending the  data via a multipart request

```
  if (jobPic !=null)
             {
               r.addData("jobPic",bytesdata,"image/jpeg" );  
             }
```

then handeling the data with php script below

```
if (isset ($_FILES["jobPic"])) {
$image = $_FILES['jobPic']['name'];
$target_path = "/uploads/";
$dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
$uid = uniqid();
$file = $uid .$image.".jpeg" ;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["jobPic"]["tmp_name"],$target_path . $file);

$jobPic =$dir. $target_path . $file;
}else {
    $jobPic = "";
```

and then the Url stored in database looks like this

```
D:localTemp/uploads/592caa9de79fdjobPic.jpeg
```

and I am unable to create an image with this url in codename one after getting url from server

Comment: That's not a URL, that's a local file on your machine a URL should be an HTTP or HTTPS URL. To get this working your server needs to deliver that image when asked for it

Comment: And how do I do that I don't know that after I sent the data via a multipart request to HTTPS://udrafter2017.azurewebsites.net/php/postjob.php  how to handle it with php script. And save it on server

Comment: In the PHP code you need to write code that provides access to that file over http. Unfortunately, I can't help you with PHP as I don't use it. Notice that this has nothing to do with Codename One and would be a problem with a web UI or any other type of UI as a client cant reach a file physically located on the server without an access API